# Android - ConsentInformation - Could not parse Event FE preflight response

Tags: android, admob, ads

I ve seen this error posted in many places but no one has ever answered what needs to be done to fix it or why is it happening. I m hoping I ll have better luck.

```
ConsentInformation consentInformation = ConsentInformation.getInstance(getActivity());
String[] publisherIds = {"pub-**********~*******"};
consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(publisherIds, new ConsentInfoUpdateListener() {


    @Override
    public void onConsentInfoUpdated(com.google.ads.consent.ConsentStatus consentStatus) {
         //do something
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailedToUpdateConsentInfo(String errorDescription) {
        Log.e("GDPR ", errorDescription);
    }
});
```

This is how I am using the consent sdk. I always get the same error: `Could not parse Event FE preflight response`

My import in gradle is     `implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.6'`
I am running this code on the OnCreateView method of the first fragment loaded. Also tried running a few seconds later in case it was a timing thing...still the same error.
Also tried adding the `ca-app-` prefix before the `pub` in publisher id...same result.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you fix this problem? I'm getting the same one. :-)

Comment: unfortunately no. I ended up always showing the consent dialog no matter if it is needed or not. I really don't understand how Google is letting this go by like this

Comment: Okay thank you :-(

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that you're using **Publisher ID** and not App ID

**Publisher ID** is the unique identifier for your AdMob account.
Looks something like this `pub-7100389293873601`

**App ID** is the unique ID assigned to your app. It looks something like this `ca-app-pub-7100382293173983~6849306728`.

You can have multiple App IDs (for each app) but you can only have one Publisher ID for your account.

You can find your publisher ID in you [AdMob](https://apps.admob.com) Settings:
[image]

Or make sure you pasted it correctly.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The Admob account I used was completely new and the "Could not parse Event FE preflight response" was displayed repeatedly. Only when I tried it with an **older account** it worked. I think you have to wait a bit for verification.

or

Another thing to try is **add your payment information** to your Admob account
like described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61423243/8779275 and also check the other points there.